# Rails - Include elasticsearch on module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

Is it possible to have the

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

on a module? and how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `included` block of [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to include these modules

Something like:

```
module MyElasticSupport
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  end

  ... some other code ...
end

class MyModel
  include MyElasticSupport

  ... some other code ...
end
```

Comment: My one challenge is in my code I would have `extend` instead of `include` for MyElasticSupport